# Perl copying data from one DB to another

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a particular problem where I need to copy data from certain tables from one DB to another DB, both running in the same instance.
It is important to note that table structures in both DBs are identical, I can't use mysqldump because I need to copy only few tables.

Since the table structure is identical, I don't know, how can I do an equivalent of `select *` from one DB and `insert *` into another DB, I really don't want to use column names, because I want that table structures are identical.
Is it correct to assume that it will be done in two steps, step 1 to select records from one DB and step two to return into another DB?

Comment: If the new tables are already there and they are identical then you know the column names. No need not to know them.

Comment: What I meant is that I don't want to write something like
`insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (1,2,3)`
I really want something like select * and insert everything, like this, I won't need to change my logic if a new column is added.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT` construct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html). If the column names are the same that is very easy, because you can just omit them alltogether.

```
INSERT INTO new SELECT * FROM old;
```

From Perl you'd run that with [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn) or die DBI->errstr;

my @tables = qw(
    foo
    bar
    customers
);

foreach my $table ( @tables ) {
    $dbh->do("INSERT INTO new_db.$table SELECT * FROM old_db.$table")
        or die $dbh->errstr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With mysqldump you can copy only somes tables:

```
mysqldump -u... -p... mydb t1 t2 t3
```

But you can use ugly thinks like :

```
my $sth=$dbh->prepare("select * from table");
while (($row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref))
{
    my $i;
    for($i=0;$i<=$#$row;$i++)
    {
        $row->[$i] = $dbh->quote($row->[$i]);
    }
    $dbh2->do("insert into table values (". join(',', @$row) . ")");
}
$sth->finish();
```

I'm not sure that thinks like that works in all case.

Comment: Do you know if it will work with the NULL values too??